# Compare a textView with a String in Kotlin

Tags: android, string, textview, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I'm trying to change a text view on my android app everytime I press the button
problem is that the 'if' actions aren't applied, as if it always returned false
why is that ?

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val lol: String = "Hello World!"
    button.setOnClickListener{
        if ( textview.equals(lol)){
    textview.setText("yeah")}
        else
    textview.setText("Hello World!")
}}}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Kotlin uses `==` for string comparison

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/equality.html

> Structural equality is checked by the `==` operation (and its negated
>   counterpart `!=`).

Also, you're trying to compare a `String` to a [`TextView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html), they are two different types, so they'll never be the same. Try:

`if( textview.text == lol) {...`

Finally, as a word of advice, don't use variable names like `lol` in code you intend to ever have to debug. It may be quick and easy to use a small variable name, but if it's not descriptive, you're gonna have a bad time trying to debug it later on, take it from my personal experience ;)

Comment: error : Operator '==' cannot be applied to 'TextView!' and 'String'

Comment: Oh, you're comparing a string to a textview, that's why, see updated answer